# JQuery Retrive data-attribute from on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, custom-data-attribute

I have a div structure like this:

```
<div class='bar'>
    <div class='contents'>
        <div class='element' data-big='join'>JOIN ME</div>
        <div class='element' data-big='play'>PLAY ME</div>
        <div class='element' data-big='list'>GO TO LIST</div>
        <div class='element' data-big='chart'>GO TO TOP 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I refer to their data attribute by onClick function?

I tried with

```
$(".bar .element").on('click', ()=> {
    alert($(this).data('big'));
});
```

But it always alert "undefined".

**EDIT:**

My assertion was bad from the beginning, I was using a lambda (or arrow) expression from the Typescript language. That makes the different meaning of the keyword "this".

the snippet:

```
$(".bar .element").on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).data('big'));
});
```

works as espected.

Comment: `.on('click', ()=>` ??? What kind of syntax is it?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of jQuery?  ["As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object"](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key)

Comment: @Wolf
.on('click', ()=> ??? What kind of syntax is it?
This is a Typescript syntax equivalent to .on('click', funtion(){});

Comment: @A.Wolff It's an [ES6 construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @A.Wolff  It looks like javascript mixed with coffescript.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Really interresting! ***oops*** forgot to say thx!

Comment: @A.Wolff It will be when enough browsers support it :)

Comment: @Plastic I guess `this` isn't referring to clicked element, some context issue. Check in your console what is `this`?

Comment: @A.Wolff Could well be a context issue - the docs for the new ES6 construct say that `this` will be the same `this` as in the surrounding block, so if Typescript is replicating this behaviour, it will cause the error described by the OP

Comment: @A.Wolff i was wrong the syntax  ".on('click',()=>{}" and ".on('click', function(){}" are not equivalent cause of the different behavior of the "this" keyword

Comment: @Plastic Just added `Typescript` tag to make your question more obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a `.barra` (***as you had in your original `JS` -- `$(".barra .element")`***) element in your HTML and you've not written the callback properly:

```
$(".bar .element").on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).data('big'));
});
```

```js
    $(".bar .element").on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).data('big'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bar'>
    <div class='contents'>
        <div class='element' data-big='join'>JOIN ME</div>
        <div class='element' data-big='play'>PLAY ME</div>
        <div class='element' data-big='list'>GO TO LIST</div>
        <div class='element' data-big='chart'>GO TO TOP 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that my original snippet had a typo for the class selector but the problem wasn't there. I had a wrong syntax on my callback function, i was using a typescript lambda syntax instead of the usual javascript syntax. Anyway, I mark your as the right answer because you used JQuery "data" method.

Answer (score 3):

you should change your function like below

```
$(".bar .element").on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data-big'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In TypeScript, the arrow function expression (`() =>`) is used to preserve the lexical scope. This means that when you use `this` inside of an arrow function, it will refer to the same scope as using `this` outside of the function.

In your case, you want the function to run with the scope of the `onclick` event, not the lexical scope, so you should avoid using the arrow function and instead use `function ()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution:

jQuery:

```
$(".bar .element").on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data-big'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/qzvfswz8/55/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "id" to do it:

```html
<div id='div1' class='element' data-big='join'>JOIN ME</div>
```

```js
$("#div1").on('click', ()=> {
    alert($(this).data('big'));
});
```

Comment: I don't want to add ID on my element